How do I make JS delete the corresponding list item
Hi Im making a list which takes the user input and places it as a list item. Each list item also gets a button which says delete. This button should delete the list item and the button. I have managed to do this however when i press the delete button it is not deleting the corresponding list item. It is deleting the first "li" . Can anyone help me to fathom out how I get the delete button to delete the corresponding "li" and not the first one in the list.


const unorderedList = document.getElementById("unorderedList");
const input = document.getElementById("item");
const addToPage = document.getElementById('addButton').onclick = function () {
    userInput = document.getElementById("item").value;
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "newDiv";
    newDiv.id = "newDiv";
    let newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newButton.innerText = "Delete";
    newButton.className = "newButton";
    newButton.id = "newButton";
    newButton.onclick = removeItem;
    const newListItem = document.createElement("li");
    newListItem.innerText = userInput;
    newListItem.className = "listItem";
    newListItem.id = "listItem";
    newDiv.appendChild(newListItem);
    newDiv.appendChild(newButton);
    unorderedList.appendChild(newDiv);

};
}
li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li button {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #666;
}
<h1>My shopping list</h1>

<div>
    <label for="item">Enter a new item:</label>
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item">
    <button id="addButton">Add item</button>
</div>



<ul id="unorderedList">

</ul>




newButton.onclick = removeItem - you failed to show us what that function actually does.

IDs need to be unique. As soon as your addToPage gets called the second time, you are violating this simple, basic rule in multiple places.

You have invalid HTML by adding same id everytime (I commented it). Your removeItem() function is also not defined. I added a function removeMe and event listener that checks for click that matches the delete button to call the removeMe function.


const unorderedList = document.getElementById("unorderedList");
const input = document.getElementById("item");
const addToPage = document.getElementById('addButton').onclick = function () {
    userInput = document.getElementById("item").value;
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "newDiv";
    // newDiv.id = "newDiv"; makes invalid HTML by non unique ID
    let newButton = document.createElement("button");
    newButton.innerText = "Delete";
    newButton.className = "newButton";
    // newButton.id = "newButton"; makes invalid HTML by non unique ID
    // newButton.onclick = removeItem();
    const newListItem = document.createElement("li");
    newListItem.innerText = userInput;
    newListItem.className = "listItem";
    // newListItem.id = "listItem"; makes invalid HTML by non unique ID
    newDiv.appendChild(newListItem);
    newDiv.appendChild(newButton);
    unorderedList.appendChild(newDiv);

};

const removeMe = function() {
    this.parentNode.remove();
  }

document.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if (event.target.matches(".newDiv .newButton")) {
      removeMe.call(event.target, event);
    }
  });
li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

li button {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #666;
}
<h1>My shopping list</h1>

<div>
    <label for="item">Enter a new item:</label>
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item">
    <button id="addButton">Add item</button>
</div>



<ul id="unorderedList">

</ul>




Thankyou for your help with this.

You are very welcome
